# Why Ecplise is not opening on Linux Mint?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Linux Mint 19.0 Tara and after updating eclipse, i couldn't open the program anymore. I already unninstalled and reinstalled a lot of times and nothing changes. The only way is using a portable executable. When i click to open the software, or via terminal, the following message is showed:

An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/usuario/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1537835421759.log

The contents of said log:

```
!SESSION Mon Sep 24 21:46:42 BRT 2018 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-09-24 21:46:42.692
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I have tried to do the things that are suggested on the other question. The problems have similarities. However, the solution doesn't work despite some modifications on the folders. I made a great mess with the environment!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're mixing a really old version of Eclipse, 3.8, with a newish version of Java. Eclipse just released version 4.9. Download it from download.eclipse.org.

Comment: Do you know how can I clean the system from the older version? I don't understand so much about packages on linux environment, so it's possibel that I made a mess with the versions.

Comment: You won't need to. It'll be the downloadable installer or a separate, mostly self-contained, compressed tar file that you should unpack/install somewhere under your home directory and then run.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. At this time, i'm using that. The question is that I think is better having the programs on the start menu, to easy and organized access. If I couldn't solve the problem, I will keep taking this way. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Look in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/` in your workspace for a file called `##.snap`, where `##` could be any numbers. Once you find it, delete it.

Comment: Hi, Joseph. Thanks for helping. Unfortunatelly, i didn't find the file. Like i said, i unninstalled the program a lot of times. This link, https://pastebin.com/f7HEd3gZ have the log I have on the message.

Comment: That's a different cause than I was expecting. I think another question answers this; I'll link to it above.

Comment: Thanks. I found some questions here but none of that could help me until now.